# C - String vs. Array in for condition

Tags: c, arrays, string

today i was trying to make a simple "program" in C, and i want to do following: When you enter Uppercase string, the program will transform all characters to lowercase. But i stupped to curiosity.

```
char uppword[26];
int i;
printf("Gimme a word in uppercase.: ");
scanf("%s", uppword);
for (i=0; i < uppword[i]; i++){
    uppword[i] = uppword[i] + 32;
}

printf("%s", uppword);

return 0;
```

As you can see, in for loop is a condition `i < uppword[i]`, but i dont know, why this is works. In other way, i can replace this condition by `i < strlen(uppword)`, and it will be also works. But i don't think that this is same as array. Why this Array works? The "i" in array is on the beginning 0, so the condition is not TRUE, and it can't be proceeded.

Comment: C does not have a string type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`uppword[i]` will be 0 at the end of the string (`scanf` does that for you unless you've tried to read too many characters in which case the compiler might eat your cat). `i < 0` will be 0 at that point. Subject to some assumptions, it is 0 *only* at that point: These assumptions are (i) `uppword` has at most less than 32 characters (you've allowed for 25 plus a nul-terminator), and (ii) in ASCII at least you *typically* don't encounter characters less than 32 (as they are the control set).

Clever, if a little hard to read.

The smart alec programmer might also want to consider the fact that this code assumes ASCII encoding, and is therefore not portable C.

Consider using `strlen` instead, but *pre-compute* that: don't include it as the loop conditional as you'll then convert an O(N) process to an O(N*N) process - only a compiler from a divinity would know that `strlen` doesn't change between iterations, given that your loop body mutates the string.

Comment: I agree with you, that's the reason, but why there is not a crash in the loop?? When is reached the condition to leave the loop? What happen when the last character is evaluated?? It will try to access to a character in uppword that does not exit

Comment: The loop ends when it reaches the nul-terimator in `uppword`.

Comment: Ahhh ok, it is appended the nul character automatically

Answer (score 0):

`uppword[i]` works because when the `i` is small, it is referring to the strings formatted with ASCII, as 'A' in ASCII is 33 always greater than `26`, your array `uppword[26]`.

When `i` is increasing until `uppword[i]` is pointing to the null-terminating character of your string, the condition will be false as `i` must be greater than 0 (the null character). Therefore it will leave the loop.

That means this loop will stop when it reaches the null character.

Answer (score 0):

> The "i" in array is on the beginning 0, so the condition is not TRUE, and it can't be proceeded.

The condition is checking if `i` is less than `upword[i]`; at the beginning, you're checking to see if `0` is less than `upword[0]`, which is almost certainly true.

Suppose you enter the string `"Hello"`.  What gets stored in `upword` is the character sequence `{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0 }`.  Each time through the loop, you're making the following comparisons:

```
0 < 'H' (72)  true
1 < 'e' (101) true
2 < 'l' (108) true
3 < 'l' (108) true
4 < 'o' (111) true
5 < 0         false
```

The loop will exit when it hits the 0 terminator, because 0 will not be greater than the index value.  Like Bathsheba says, this code assumes the string will never contain any control characters.

As written, this is not good code - it makes all kinds of assumptions about the underlying character set, it's not clear, and it's not safe.  A better version would be something like

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
scanf( "%25s", upword );  // use an explicit field with modifier so that
                          // we don't try to store more characters than
                          // upword is sized to hold.  Leave room for trailing 0

for ( char *p = upword; *p != 0; p++ )
  *p = toupper( *p );
```

This code iterates through the string using a pointer `p`, and loops until it sees the `0` string terminator.  It also uses the `toupper` library function, which a) takes the current character encoding (ASCII, EBCDIC, whatever) into account, and b) returns the original character if no uppercase equivalent is available (such as for punctuation characters).